# how to center a a tikz over another tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgflayers

I would like to center the pi symbol in the spiral of the digits of pi.
And would like to know if its possible to change the color of the digits under the pi symbol? as it stands I have the digits visible but would like the font to also change color.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  decoration={
    reverse path,
    text effects along path,
    text={%
3{,}%
    141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034     8253421170679%
  821480865132823066470938446095505822317253594081284811174502841027019385211055596446229. 4895493038196%
 442881097566593344612847564823378678316527120190914564856692346034861045432664821339360     7260249141273%
     724587006606315588174881520920962829254091715364367892590360011330530548820466521384146     9519415116094%
 330572703657595919530921861173819326117931051185480744623799627495673518857527248912279     3818301194912%
  983367336244065664308602139494639522473719070217986094370277053921717629317675238467481     8467669405132%
 000568127145263560827785771342757789609173637178721468440901224953430146549585371050792     2796892589235%
 420199561121290219608640344181598136297747713099605187072113499999983729780499510597317     3281609631859%
 502445945534690830264252230825334468503526193118817101000313783875288658753320838142061      7177669147303%
 598253490428755468731159562863882353787593751957781857780532171226806613001927876611195      9092164201989%
  380952572010654858632788659361533818279682303019520353018529689957736225994138912497217      7528347913151%
  557485724245415069595082953311686172785588907509838175463746493931925506040092770167113      9009848824012%
  858361603563707660104710181942955596198946767837449448255379774726847104047534646208046      6842590694912%
  933136770289891521047521620569660240580381501935112533824300355876402474964732639141992      7260426992279%
  678235478163600934172164121992458631503028618297455570674983850549458858692699569092721      0797509302955%
  321165344987202755960236480665499119881834797753566369807426542527862551818417574672890      9777727938000%
 816470600161452491921732172147723501414419735685481613611573525521334757418494684385233     2390739414333%
  454776241686251898356948556209921922218427255025425688767179049460165346680498862723279      1786085784383%
  827967976681454100953883786360950680064225125205117392984896084128488626945604241965285      0222106611863%
  067442786220391949450471237137869609563643719172874677646575739624138908658326459958133       9047802759009%
  946576407895126946839835259570982582262052248940772671947826848260147699090264013639443     7455305068203%
  496252451749399651431429809190659250937221696461515709858387410597885959772975498930161      7539284681382%
  686838689427741559918559252459539594310499725246808459872736446958486538367362226260991      2460805124388%
  439045124413654976278079771569143599770012961608944169486855584840635342207222582848864      8158456028506%
  016842739452267467678895252138522549954666727823986456596116354886230577456498035593634       5681743241125%
  150760694794510965960940252288797108931456691368672287489405601015033086179286809208747      6091782493858%
  900971490967598526136554978189312978482168299894872265880485756401427047755513237964145      1523746234364%
  542858444795265867821051141354735739523113427166102135969536231442952484937187110145765      4035902799344%
 037420073105785390621983874478084784896833214457138687519435064302184531910484810053706      1468067491927%
 819119793995206141966342875444064374512371819217999839101591956181467514269123974894090     7186494231961%
    },
    text effects/.cd,
      text along path,
      character count=\i, character total=\n,
      characters={scale=1-\i/\n}
    }
]
\draw [decorate] (0,0) 
    \foreach \i [evaluate={\r=(\i/1800)^2;}] in {0,5,...,4000}{ -- (\i:\r)}; 
   
\filldraw[blue,opacity=0.7] (-3.32,1.88) .. controls (-2.62,4.28) and (0.04,2.87)           .. (1.48,3.41) .. controls (1.38,2.54) and (0.57,2.53) .. (0.09,2.48) .. controls   (0.08,1.03) and (-0.48,-1.4) .. (0.82,-0.31) .. controls (0.78,-1.24) and (-1.71,-2.57)   .. (-0.31,2.51) .. controls (-0.87,2.5) and (-0.87,2.5) .. (-1.48,2.53) .. controls   (-1.49,1.31) and (-2.05,-1.77) .. (-2.93,-1.1) .. controls (-3.48,-0.36) and  (-2.27,-0.74) .. (-1.88,2.55) .. controls (-2.47,2.51) and (-2.79,2.36) ..  (-3.32,1.88);    

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And if anybody does know a way to create the digits of pi instead of typing copy and pasting them into the code that would be great but, I think its just a matter of some python code so I might be able to solve it. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just doing

```
\filldraw[blue, opacity=0.7] (-3.32,1.88) .. controls (-2.62,4.28) and (0.04,2.87) .. (1.48,3.41) .. controls (1.38,2.54) and (0.57,2.53) .. (0.09,2.48) .. controls   (0.08,1.03) and (-0.48,-1.4) .. (0.82,-0.31) .. controls (0.78,-1.24) and (-1.71,-2.57)   .. (-0.31,2.51) .. controls (-0.87,2.5) and (-0.87,2.5) .. (-1.48,2.53) .. controls   (-1.49,1.31) and (-2.05,-1.77) .. (-2.93,-1.1) .. controls (-3.48,-0.36) and  (-2.27,-0.74) .. (-1.88,2.55) .. controls (-2.47,2.51) and (-2.79,2.36) ..  (-3.32,1.88);    
\path (current bounding box.center);
\pgfgetlastxy\xxx\yyy
\typeout{\xxx, \yyy}
```

gives us

```
-28.45274pt, 24.32698pt
```

in the log file, meaning the center of that pi symbol is at that coordinate.
Simply shifting the pi path in the reverse direction gives us a path that is centered around (0, 0). More fine-tuning is needed if you don't like that.

For the characters, I'm just using a similar style as [the example in the manual](https://tikz.dev/library-decorations#sec-50.7):

```
characters={
  scale=1-\i/\n,
  text depth=+0pt,
  text height=+.7em,
  /utils/exec=\pgfmathparse{\i/\n*100},
  text=red!\pgfmathresult!green
}
```

This will give you

[image]

---

I've commented out over half your digits because the path wasn't long enough.
Remaining characters don't get added to the spiral and it doesn't look good because the scaling factor doesn't reach 0.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt, convert]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  decoration={
    reverse path,
    text effects along path,
    text={%
      3{,}%
      1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679%
      8214808651328230664709384460955058223172535940812848111745028410270193852110555964462294895493038196%
      4428810975665933446128475648233786783165271201909145648566923460348610454326648213393607260249141273%
      7245870066063155881748815209209628292540917153643678925903600113305305488204665213841469519415116094%
      3305727036575959195309218611738193261179310511854807446237996274956735188575272489122793818301194912%
      9833673362440656643086021394946395224737190702179860943702770539217176293176752384674818467669405132%
      0005681271452635608277857713427577896091736371787214684409012249534301465495853710507922796892589235%
      4201995611212902196086403441815981362977477130996051870721134999999837297804995105973173281609631859%
      5024459455346908302642522308253344685035261931188171010003137838752886587533208381420617177669147303%
      5982534904287554687311595628638823537875937519577818577805321712268066130019278766111959092164201989%
      3809525720106548586327886593615338182796823030195203530185296899577362259941389124972177528347913151%
      5574857242454150695950829533116861727855889075098381754637464939319255060400927701671139009848824012%
      8583616035637076601047101819429555961989467678374494482553797747268471040475346462080466842590694912%
%      9331367702898915210475216205696602405803815019351125338243003558764024749647326391419927260426992279%
%      6782354781636009341721641219924586315030286182974555706749838505494588586926995690927210797509302955%
%      3211653449872027559602364806654991198818347977535663698074265425278625518184175746728909777727938000%
%      8164706001614524919217321721477235014144197356854816136115735255213347574184946843852332390739414333%
%      4547762416862518983569485562099219222184272550254256887671790494601653466804988627232791786085784383%
%      8279679766814541009538837863609506800642251252051173929848960841284886269456042419652850222106611863%
%      0674427862203919494504712371378696095636437191728746776465757396241389086583264599581339047802759009%
%      9465764078951269468398352595709825822620522489407726719478268482601476990902640136394437455305068203%
%      4962524517493996514314298091906592509372216964615157098583874105978859597729754989301617539284681382%
%      6868386894277415599185592524595395943104997252468084598727364469584865383673622262609912460805124388%
%      4390451244136549762780797715691435997700129616089441694868555848406353422072225828488648158456028506%
%      0168427394522674676788952521385225499546667278239864565961163548862305774564980355936345681743241125%
%      1507606947945109659609402522887971089314566913686722874894056010150330861792868092087476091782493858%
%      9009714909675985261365549781893129784821682998948722658804857564014270477555132379641451523746234364%
%      5428584447952658678210511413547357395231134271661021359695362314429524849371871101457654035902799344%
%      0374200731057853906219838744780847848968332144571386875194350643021845319104848100537061468067491927%
%      8191197939952061419663428754440643745123718192179998391015919561814675142691239748940907186494231961%
    },
    text effects/.cd,
      text along path,
      character count=\i, character total=\n,
      characters={
        scale/.expanded=1-\i/\n,
        text depth=+0pt,
        text height=+.7em,
        /utils/exec=\pgfmathparse{\i/\n*100},
        text=red!\pgfmathresult!green
      }
  }
]
\draw [decorate] (0,0) 
  \foreach \i [evaluate={\r=(\i/1800)^2;}] in {0,5,...,4000}{ -- (\i:\r)}; 
   
\filldraw[shift={(28.45274pt, -24.32698pt)}, blue, opacity=0.7]
  (-3.32,1.88) .. controls (-2.62,4.28) and (0.04,2.87) .. (1.48,3.41)
               .. controls (1.38,2.54) and (0.57,2.53) .. (0.09,2.48)
               .. controls   (0.08,1.03) and (-0.48,-1.4) .. (0.82,-0.31)
               .. controls (0.78,-1.24) and (-1.71,-2.57) .. (-0.31,2.51)
               .. controls (-0.87,2.5) and (-0.87,2.5) .. (-1.48,2.53)
               .. controls (-1.49,1.31) and (-2.05,-1.77) .. (-2.93,-1.1)
               .. controls (-3.48,-0.36) and  (-2.27,-0.74).. (-1.88,2.55)
               .. controls (-2.47,2.51) and (-2.79,2.36) ..  (-3.32,1.88);
%\path (current bounding box.center);
%\pgfgetlastxy\xxx\yyy
%\typeout{\xxx, \yyy}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting with the code from @Qrrbrbirlbel, I use a `local bounding box` to avoid manual shifting. A `bezier bounding box` from `bbox` gives a better bounding box. -only by chance are their centers close.

[image: Large pi symbol inside two boxes]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text, bbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
decoration={
reverse path,
text effects along path,
text={%
3{,}%
1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679%
8214808651328230664709384460955058223172535940812848111745028410270193852110555964462294895493038196%
4428810975665933446128475648233786783165271201909145648566923460348610454326648213393607260249141273%
7245870066063155881748815209209628292540917153643678925903600113305305488204665213841469519415116094%
3305727036575959195309218611738193261179310511854807446237996274956735188575272489122793818301194912%
9833673362440656643086021394946395224737190702179860943702770539217176293176752384674818467669405132%
0005681271452635608277857713427577896091736371787214684409012249534301465495853710507922796892589235%
4201995611212902196086403441815981362977477130996051870721134999999837297804995105973173281609631859%
5024459455346908302642522308253344685035261931188171010003137838752886587533208381420617177669147303%
5982534904287554687311595628638823537875937519577818577805321712268066130019278766111959092164201989%
3809525720106548586327886593615338182796823030195203530185296899577362259941389124972177528347913151%
5574857242454150695950829533116861727855889075098381754637464939319255060400927701671139009848824012%
8583616035637076601047101819429555961989467678374494482553797747268471040475346462080466842590694912%
},
text effects/.cd,
text along path,
character count=\i, character total=\n,
characters={
scale/.expanded=1-\i/\n,
text depth=+0pt,
text height=+.7em,
/utils/exec=\pgfmathparse{\i/\n*100},
text=red!\pgfmathresult!green
}}]
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background, main, foreground}
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=pi, bezier bounding box]
\shade[top color=blue, bottom color=red, opacity=0.7, scale=1.4]
(-3.32,1.88) .. controls (-2.62,4.28) and (0.04,2.87) .. (1.48,3.41)
.. controls (1.38,2.54) and (0.57,2.53) .. (0.09,2.48)
.. controls (0.08,1.03) and (-0.48,-1.4) .. (0.82,-0.31)
.. controls (0.78,-1.24) and (-1.71,-2.57) .. (-0.31,2.51)
.. controls (-0.87,2.5) and (-0.87,2.5) .. (-1.48,2.53)
.. controls (-1.49,1.31) and (-2.05,-1.77) .. (-2.93,-1.1)
.. controls (-3.48,-0.36) and  (-2.27,-0.74).. (-1.88,2.55)
.. controls (-2.47,2.51) and (-2.79,2.36) .. (-3.32,1.88);
\end{scope}
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\draw[decorate, shift=(pi.center)] (0,0) \foreach \i [evaluate={\r=(\i/1800)^2;}] in {0,5,...,4000}{ -- (\i:\r)}; 
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Large pi symbol with the digits in a spiral]